# Possibilities to place $20$ different persons onto $25$ seats

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There's a room with $25$ seats.

How many possibilities are there to place 20 different persons onto it?

I thought about calculating $${25 \choose 20} =5310 $$

But don't I have to multiply that result with $20!$ now? Wouldn't the result be too big?

And **how many possibilities are there to place $10$ groups of two so that the groups are always next to each other?**

Comment: A number can be very big without being *too* big

Comment: That's fine right? You first calculate the number of different ways to choose 20 people from 25, then the number of ways to permute those people. For each choosing of people, you have to calculate permutations, so multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should multiply it with $20!$.

Also you can do like that: First one has $25$ choises, second one $24$, and so on till the last one who has 6 choises. So the answer is $$25\cdot 24\cdot...\cdot 7\cdot 6 = {25!\over 5!} $$
which is surprisingly the same as $${25\choose 20}\cdot 20!$$

---

For the second question: You have $10$ pairs and $5$ imaginary people. You can distribute them on $${15!\cdot 2^{10}\over 5!}$$ ways on $25$ chairs. We should divide it by $5!$ since any pemutation of this imaginary people is the same distibution.

Comment: $\frac{25!}{5!}$ is not *surprisingly* the same as ${25 \choose 20} \cdot 20!$. $\frac{25!}{5!} = \frac{25!}{20! \cdot 5!} \cdot 20! = {25 \choose 20} \cdot 20!$.